# How Do I Add Dynamic Sub Collection Data In Firestore In SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, swiftui

I'm new to swift and firebase and am trying lots of things out. I have created a collection of "characters" in firebase which are displayed in the app. The aim is there are "characters" you unlock by earning points. Points are earned by walking (getting steps using HealthKit)

When a user taps on a character and then taps "unlock" its added to a struct called UnlockingCharacters.

UnlockingCharacters are shown in the users profile.

I need to make the UnlockingCharacters struct part of the users document on Firebase (maybe as a subcollection?)

I want to limit the number of characters in UnlockingCharacters to 2. Characters are unlocked by taking steps which are turned into points. When points are uploaded to firebase, the character receives these points and adds it to its total (a characters points total is the sum of all users that are unlocking the characters points).

Here is the Character Model:

```
struct Character: Identifiable, Decodable {
    
@DocumentID var id: String?
    var character_name: String
    var character_type: String
    var character_image: String
    var character_details: String
    var character_usersUnlocking: Int
    var character_totalPoints: Int
    var user: UserModel?
    var didUnlock: Bool? = false
      
    // To identify whether it is being unlocked...
    var isUnlocking: Bool = false
    
}
```

Here is the UnlockingCharacters model:

```
struct UnlockingCharacters: Identifiable {
    
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var character: Character
}
```

SharedDataModel:

```
class SharedDataModel: ObservableObject {
   
    // Unlocking Characters...
    @Published var unlockingCharacters: [Character] = [] 
}
```

My Functions:

```
 func isUnlocked() -> Bool {
        
        return sharedData.unlockingCharacters.contains { characterData in
            return self.characterData.id == characterData.id
        }
    }

    func addToUnlocking() {

        if let index = sharedData.unlockingCharacters.firstIndex(where: {

            characterData in
            return self.characterData.id == characterData.id
        }){
            // Remove from unlocking...
            sharedData.unlockingCharacters.remove(at: index)
        }
        else {
            // Add to unlocking...
            sharedData.unlockingCharacters.append(characterData)
        }
    }
```

I know that something needs to be added to my UserModel too however I am getting an error:

```
struct UserModel: Identifiable, Decodable {
    var username : String
    var pic : String
    var bio: String
    var uid : String
    var id: String { uid }  

//I am getting error for the following variable:
(Value type 'UserModel' cannot have a stored property that recursively contains it)

    var activeUnlockingCharacters: UnlockingCharacters
}
```

To sum up I need UnlockingCharacters to be added to the users document on Firebase.

I'm getting an error processing a custom object. Here is my code:

```
let ref = Firestore.firestore()

func fetchUser(uid: String,completion: @escaping (UserModel) -> ()){
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    ref.collection("Users").document(uid).getDocument { (doc, err) in
        guard let user = doc else{return}
        
        let username = user.data()?["username"] as? String ?? "No Username"
        let pic = user.data()?["imageurl"] as? String ?? "No image URL"
        let bio = user.data()?["bio"] as? String ?? "No bio"
        let uid = user.data()?["uid"] as? String ?? ""
 
        do {
            try db.collection("Users").document("\(uid)").setData(from: UnlockingCharacters)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error writing object to Firestore: \(error)")
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(UserModel(username: username, pic: pic, bio: bio, uid: uid, activeUnlockingCharacters: UnlockingCharacters))
        }
    }
}
```

The error in the do is: "Type 'UnlockingCharacters.Type' cannot conform to 'Encodable'"

The error in the DispatchQueue is: "Cannot convert value of type 'UnlockingCharacters.Type' to expected argument type '[UnlockingCharacters]'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `var user: UserModel?` in `Character`

Then you can find the characters under `activeUnlockingCharacters`

or something like

```
UserModel/{uid}/UnlockingCharacters
```

You can make

```
var activeUnlockingCharacters: UnlockingCharacters
```

An Array

```
var activeUnlockingCharacters: [UnlockingCharacters]
```

Then use validation or rules to limit the count to 2

Firebase has a whole section on how to process custom objects.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects

if you have all your structs conform to Codable

```
do {
    try db.collection("UserModel").document("\(uid)").setData(from: userModelObject)
} catch let error {
    print("Error writing object to Firestore: \(error)")
}
```

And to read

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

```
let docRef = db.collection("UserModel").document("\(uid)")

docRef.getDocument(as: UserModel.self) { result in
    // The Result type encapsulates deserialization errors or
    // successful deserialization, and can be handled as follows:
    //
    //      Result
    //        /\
    //   Error  UserModel
    switch result {
    case .success(let userModel):
        // A `Model` value was successfully initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
        print("Model: \(userModel)")
    case .failure(let error):
        // A `Model` value could not be initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
        print("Error decoding object: \(error)")
    }
}
```

You can also user the new `@FirestoreQuery` and use rules to limit the object that is visible

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestoreswift/api/reference/Structs/FirestoreQuery

Set in the rules that the user is the only one that can read its own UserModel based on auth.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. However in my fetchUser function I'm unsure how to implement the activeUnlockingCharacters part because I have only dealt with Strings and Ints. For example:  let username = user.data()?["username"] as? String ?? "No Username" is pretty straight forward because it is a String. How do I do this with activeUnlockingCharacters?

Comment: @mbby You just use `Codable` and the `setData` method with the whole object. See above

Comment: Okay that you. This Codable stuff is a new concept to me. If I make the Character struct conform to Codable it gives an error: Redundant conformance of 'Charity' to protocol 'Decodable'. Does that mean I no longer need Decodable?

Comment: @mbby correct Codable contains both Decodable and Encodable that way you can read and write the object vs just read. it takes a little but to get used to but when you do it will be a breeze, you might have to add a `?` at the end of all your variables. That way if your current objects are missing a variable it won't fail the decoding because it is optional

Comment: @mbby if I answered your question can you please accept the answer with the green checkmark above?

Comment: Thanks that's the information I needed! Just need to implement it now. One error I can't get around is making the UserModel Codable. I get the error: "'Type 'UserModel' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'"

Comment: @mbby all the variables should be of a `Codable` type so make sure you make `Character` and `UnlockingCharachers` `Codable`

Comment: I have made Character and UnlockingCharacters both Codable but I am still getting the error: Type 'UnlockingCharacters.Type' cannot conform to 'Encodable'. Is there another reason for this error or have I missed a variable when making them Codable?

Comment: @mbby the only thing I can think of from your code is that the id has a default value. Make a custom initializer and set it from there. The fire base init might not like that

Comment: Okay, I'm struggling to get my head around processing the custom object. I'll edit the question to show my code and the error